# Convert string to date using datefinder

Tags: python, datetime, datefinder

An issue occurs when I try to find a date in a .txt file using datefinder. I have the feeling I am unnecessarily switching between data types to obtain the result I desire.

Underneath is a MWE which results in generator object, which in turn is empty when changed to a list. I would like to obtain a datetime in the format %d-%m-%Y.
MWE:

```
import datefinder 

f = ['this is text', 'this is a date', '* Model creation date:            Sun Apr 25 08:52:06 2021']
for line in f:
    if "creation date" in line: 
        date_line = str(line)
        rev_date = datefinder.find_dates(_date_line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)'s parser seems to do a better job:

```
import dateutil

f = ['this is text', 'this is a date', '* Model creation date:            Sun Apr 25 08:52:06 2021']
dates = []

for line in f:
    try:
        dates.append(dateutil.parser.parse(line, fuzzy=True))
    except dateutil.parser.ParserError:
        pass
    
print(dates)    
# [datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 25, 8, 52, 6)]
```

For the specific use-case:

```
for line in f:
    if "* Model creation date:" in line:
        rev_date = dateutil.parser.parse(line, fuzzy=True)
        break
print(rev_date)    
# 2021-04-25 08:52:06
```

Comment: This option works for the the presented MWE. However I would like to find the specific line '* Model creation date:            Sun Apr 25 08:52:06 2021' in the list from a much larger dataset than presented, which also contains more dates that are irrelevant when advancing in the script.

Comment: @Frits sure, made an edit to include that specific case.

Comment: @Frits glad I could help! You might also want to catch the case if the specific line containing the date is *not* found.

Answer (score 2):

Seems `datefinder.find_dates` works based on `:`. If you can remove `:` character after `creation date` get right result.
If always your string include `creation date:` you can remove this substring after `if` statement:

```
import datefinder 

f = ['this is text', 'this is a date', '* Model creation date:            Sun Apr 25 08:52:06 2021']
for line in f:
    if "creation date" in line: 
        date_line = line.replace('creattion date:', '')
        rev_date = datefinder.find_dates(date_line)
```

Comment: nice to spot the ":" problem :) seems kind of a work-around though, the finder shouldn't trip on such things, no?

Comment: Yes, I think this seems like a bug in `datefinder` library.